Entropy arguments used by Jean Bourgain
My question comes from understanding a probabilistic inequality in Bourgain's paper on Erdős simiarilty problem: Construction of sets of positive measure not containing an affine image of a given infinite structure. Israel J. Math. 60, 333–344 (1987).
In the pape 343 of the paper, for $J$ large and $x=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_j)\in\mathbb{R}^J$, we define
$$|x|_0:=\frac{1}{J}\#\{1\leq j\leq J: |x_j|>\frac{1}{100}\}.$$
Now let $\{g_i(\omega)\}_{1\leq i\leq J}$ be independent Gaussian variables and $G:=(g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_J).$
Bourgain asserted that using elementary Entropy considerations, we could straightforwardly show that for any subspace $E\subset \mathbb{R}^J$ with dimension $J/100$, the following inequality holds
$$\mathbb{P}\Big\{\inf_{x\in E}|G-x|_0\leq\frac{1}{100}\Big\}<\mathrm{e}^{-J}.$$
The original paper wrote $x\in X$ not $x\in E$, but I guess it was a typo.
My questions:

What is the entropy consideration that Bourgain used?
I also saw other papers by Bourgain where the so called entropy argument is frequently used. For example, in the same paper, formula (39) in page 344, he said that we can control the number $\alpha$ by entropy argument. However, I can not find a detailed explanation of this argument. Is there a reference/exposition on this method?

I knew that Terence Tao had a paper exploring the toolkit of Jean Bourgain, which spent a section explaining the technique of metric entropy and concentration of measure. However, I had no idea how to derive the desired inequality from this method. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Tao also has more recent blogposts where entropy methods are used, such as the latest one on Marton's conjecture. Not sure if they're applicable.

What follows is a bit of Computer-Sciency exposition, but since it proves the desired claim and it is an "elementary entropy consideration" I hope it answers the question.
For convenience, let us take $n := |J|$.  Let $E$ be a given subspace of dimension $n/100$, and let us consider a collection of subspaces $A_I := E + T_{I}$ for $I \subset [J]$ of size $|I| = n/100 =: k$, where $T_I = \{ v : \mathop{supp}(v) \subset I\}$, and let $\mathcal{A} = \bigcup_I A_I$ be the union of those subspaces.
We want to show that for $Z \sim N(0, I)$, the probability that there is some $u \in \mathcal{A}$ s.t. $\|Z - u\|_\infty \leq 1/100$ is small. If we denote by $P_r$ the probability of this event when the vector $Z := (Z_1, \ldots Z_n)$ is instead drawn uniformly at random from a sphere of radius $r$, it is easy to see that $P_r$ is non-increasing. Hence, the probability that $Z \sim N(0, I)$ is $1/100$-close in $\ell_\infty$ to a vector from $\mathcal{A}$ is upper bounded by the probability of this event conditioned on $|Z| \leq 2 \sqrt{n}$. Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be the Gaussian distribution conditioned on $|Z| \leq 2 \sqrt{n}$ from now on.
We will see that if the probability in question was at least $\delta$, we could encode $n$ uniformly random bits into a string of at most $n/2$ bits,  with probability close to $\delta$ of being able to correctly recover $0.9 n$ of those bits out of the encoding.
More concretely, we will construct a (randomised) encoding function $f : \{\pm 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}^{n/2}$ and a decoding function $g : \{0, 1\}^{n/2} \to \{\pm 1\}^n$, such that for a uniformly random $X \sim \{\pm 1\}^n$ we have
$$
\Pr(d_H(g(f(X)) , X) \leq 0.1 n) \geq \delta - \exp(-\Omega(n))
$$
where $d_H(u,v) = | \{ i: u_i \not= v_i\}|$ is the Hamming distance on the hypercube $\{\pm 1\}^n$. Later we will see how this implies an upper bound on the recovery probability $\delta \leq \exp(-\Omega(n))$.
Lemma 1
There is a set $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, of size $|\mathcal{N}| \leq 2^{n/2}$ s.t. for all $v \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\|v\| \leq 3 \sqrt{n}$, there is some $u \in \mathcal{N}$ with $\|u - v\|_2 \leq 2^{-14} \sqrt{n}$. (i.e. $(\varepsilon \sqrt{n})$-net for this set with respect to $\ell_2$-norm with $\varepsilon = 2^{-14}$).
Proof.
Each subspace $A_I$ is of dimension $d = n/50$, and it is well-known that there is an $\varepsilon$-net for such an unit $\ell_2$ ball in a eucleadian space of dimension $d$ with size at most $(4/\varepsilon)^{d}$. We can choose a net of size $2^{n/3}$, which is an $\varepsilon$-net for $\varepsilon \leq 2^{-16}$. Rescaling it to the ball of radius $3\sqrt{n}$, gives us a net with $\varepsilon = 2^{-14} \sqrt{n}$. Finally, since there are $\binom{n}{k}$ subspaces $A_I$ to consider, we apply the same construction to each such subspace, yielding the total size of the net $|\mathcal{N}| \leq \binom{n}{k} 2^{n/3}$, or $\log |N| \leq n/3 + k \log (n/k) = n/3 + (n/100) \log(100) \leq n/2$.
$\square$
Now, let us pretend that for a random vector $Z \sim \mathcal{Q}$ with probability at least $\delta$ we have $\ell_{\infty}(Z, \mathcal{A}) \leq 1/100$.
The encoding $f$ is rather simple: given $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$, let us sample $(Z_1, Z_2, \ldots Z_n) \sim \mathcal{Q}$, and take $\tilde{Z}_i := |Z_i| X_i$. Note that $\tilde{Z}_i$ has jointly distribution $\mathcal{Q}$ again, hence by our assumption, with probability at least $\delta$, there is some $u \in \mathcal{A}$, with $\|u - \tilde{Z}\|_\infty \leq 1/100$. Since $\|u\|_2 \leq \|\tilde{Z}\|_2 + \sqrt{n} \|u - \tilde{Z}\|_\infty \leq 3 \sqrt{n}$, we can use the property of the construction in Lemma 1, to conclude that there is some $v \in \mathcal{N}$ with $\|u - v\|_2 \leq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}$. The encoding $f$ will map the signs $X_1, \ldots X_n$ to an index of $v$ in $\mathcal{N}$ (which can be written using at most $\log_2 |\mathcal{N}| \leq n/2$ bits), and the decoding $g$ will take index $i$ of a net elemenet $u \in \mathcal{N}$ and map it back to a vector $(\mathop{sgn}(u_1), \ldots \mathop{sgn}(u_n))$.
All we have to show is that with probability at least $\delta - \exp(-\Omega(n))$, we can recover $0.9 n$ among the random bits $X_i$. Indeed, in expectation there is at most $(\Phi(0.02) - \Phi(-0.02)) n$ coordinates of $\tilde{Z}$ with $|\tilde{Z}_i| \leq 2/100$, and by Chernoff bound with probability at least $1 - \exp(-\Omega(n))$, there is at most $0.05 n$ such coordinates. On the other hand, among the $0.95 n$ coordinates for which $|\tilde{Z}_i| > 0.02$, we will incorrectly recover at most $(\varepsilon^2/0.01) n$ --- i.e. for all those coordinates we have $\mathop{sgn}(u_i) = X_i$ and $|u_i| > 0.01 =: \gamma$, and since $\|u - v\|_2 \leq \varepsilon \sqrt{n}$, we could have at most $(\varepsilon^2/\gamma^2) n$ of those coordinates $i$ for which $\mathop{sgn}(u_i) \not= \mathop{sgn}(v_i)$.
Finally, let us show that such an encoding is impossible
Lemma 2
Consider a randomised encoding $f : \{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}^{n/2}$ and decoding $g : \{0, 1\}^{n/2} \to \{0, 1\}^n$, then for uniformly random $X \in \{0, 1\}^n$ we have
$$
\Pr(d_H(g(f(X)), X) \leq 0.1 n) \leq \exp(-\Omega(n)).
$$
Proof.
Let $\mathcal{B} \subset \{0,1\}^n$ be given as $\mathcal{B} := \bigcup_{y \in \mathop{Im}(g)} B_H(y, 0.1n)$, where $B_H(y, \delta)$ is a hamming ball at $y$ of radius $\delta$, i.e. $B_H(y, \delta) := \{ z \in \{0,1\}^n : d_H(z,y) \leq \delta)$.
Clearly,
$$
\Pr(d_H(g(f(X)), X) \leq 0.1 n) \leq \Pr(X \in \mathcal{B}) 
 \leq 2^{-n}|\mathop{Im}(g)| |B_H(0, 0.1n)|.
$$
Since $|B_H(y, \delta)| \leq 2^{n H(\delta/n)}$, where $H(p) := p \log(1/p) + (1-p) \log (1/(1-p))$ is a binary entropy function (see for example here), we have
$$
\Pr(X \in \mathcal{B})  \leq 2^{n(-1/2 + H(0.1))} \leq \exp(-\Omega(n)).
$$

Thanks for comments. I'm a little busy recently and I will check the answer later. At first glance, this is far from elementary at least for me...
